# Most efficient way to take sequential substrings python

Tags: python

Let's say I have `abcdefgh`. I want all the sequential substrings of length `k`. So for this string if `k = 4`, I would want `abcd` `bcde` `cdef` `defg` `efgh`. I would just loop through with the indices, but is there a more "pythonic" way?

Comment: Do you want *efficient*, or *Pythonic*? Python values obviousness and readability over efficiency (because coder efficiency > program efficiency in Python's world).

Comment: Hm, efficient would be good

Comment: How are you processing the substrings and how many do you have?  If you process them one at a time, and have a lot, a generator may be a good way to go for efficiency

Comment: Have you determined that you need the most efficient implementation?  Programmers are notoriously bad at predicting where their bottlenecks will be.  I advise that you code using the clear and obvious solution and then optimize if the performance is unacceptable.  (I do this all the time and it is exceedingly rare that I have to go back and optimize even though I process large data sets.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
In [13]: s = "abcdefgh"

In [14]: [s[i:i+4] for i in xrange(len(s)-3)]
Out[14]: ['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef', 'defg', 'efgh']
```

Still a loop, but wrapped in a list comprehension.

Or, if you want to get fancy:

```
In [18]: map(''.join, zip(*(s[i:] for i in range(4))))
Out[18]: ['abcd', 'bcde', 'cdef', 'defg', 'efgh']
```

(Personally, I wouldn't use the latter as it's rather obtuse.)

Comment: I would if I could, but I can't improve on it.